# Is there a way to create a CloudWatch event after n inserts in database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I currently have many invocations of lambda functions that are invoked when messages are present in an SQS queue. These lambda functions insert data into a database. I need a way to trigger a lambda function after all messages have been processed. My thought was to create a Cloudwatch Event after all n insert operations happen in the database, but I cannot find documentation that shows this is possible. Would this be a good way to go about this problem? And is it possible to create a Cloudwatch event after N inserts happen on a database table?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the following steps:

1. Create a Cloudwatch alarm for when the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric is equal to zero (meaning the SQS queue is empty)
2. Configure the Cloudwatch alarm to send a message to an SNS topic
3. Configure the lambda function to subscribe to the SNS topic

---

Do note that the metrics for a standard queue are "approximate"; if you want exactness you need a FIFO queue. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html):

> For standard queues, the result is approximate because of the distributed architecture of Amazon SQS. In most cases, the count should be close to the actual number of messages in the queue.
> For FIFO queues, the result is exact.

You should, however, be able to mitigate this by configuring the sample period of the alarm to be long enough.